# Should ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator instance be thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee, websocket, tyrus

I want to share some information between websocket connections. The shared data is a bit complex so I can not use `EndpointConfig.getUserProperties()`. I want to extend `ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator` and add my own data structures.(I don't want to override other methods such as `getEndpointInstance`). The question is should I use thread safe data structures? Or I can use any data structure and web socket container will guarantee that my instance of `ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator` will be accessed in safe manner.

Answer (score 1):

That feels so hacky.
Configurator is expected to be immutable (check [Tyrus configurator for example](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish.tyrus.bundles/websocket-ri-bundle/1.2/org/glassfish/tyrus/server/TyrusServerEndpointConfigurator.java)) and not intended to be a sharing point.
In Java EE environment there is a better approach.
Websocket spec provides some support for CDI/EJB. You can inject an `@ApplicationScoped` or `@Singleton` bean and use it to share data (the bean has to be synchronized).
There's a shared counter example from [Tyrus samples on Github](https://github.com/tyrus-project/tyrus/tree/master/samples/cdi/src/main/java/org/glassfish/tyrus/sample/cdi)